Prove that there is a nonzero homomorphism between two CM elliptic curves if and only if their Mumford-Tate groups are isomorphic.
I figure out the "$\implies$" direction. But I don't know how to prove the converse statement:
Suppose $E_1,E_2$ are two elliptic curves with complex multiplication over $\mathbb{C}$. Then there exists $\tau_1,\tau_2 \in \{z\in \mathbb{C} \mid \mathrm{Im}(z)>0\}$ such that $E_i$ can be viewed as a complex torus $E_{i}=\mathbb{C} / \Lambda_{\tau_i}$. Here we define lattice $\Lambda_{\tau_i}=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\tau_i\subset\mathbb{C}$.
$E_i$ is a elliptic curve with CM means that $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\tau_i)$ is a field extension of degree 2.
Now following Moonen, the Mumford-Tate group associated to $E_i$ is $T_i=\mathbb{Q}(\tau_i)^{\times}$ viewed as a algebraic torus over $\mathbb{Q}$. i.e.
$$
T_i=\mathbb{Q}(\tau_i)^{\times}=\{\begin{pmatrix}
        x&-d_iy\\y&x
        \end{pmatrix} \mid x,y\in\mathbb{Q}, x^2+d_iy^2\neq 0\}=\mathrm{Spec}{(\mathbb{Q}[x,y,\frac{1}{x^2+d_iy^2}])}
$$
Where $d_i$ is defined as $\mathbb{Q}(\tau_i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d_i})$ for some $d\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$.
I guess $T_1\simeq T_2$ implies $d_1=d_2$, but I don't know why.
I am not familiar with algebraic group/group scheme/algebraic torus.
